# Taxable field is update, but register still doesn't show an item is taxable

Tags: square-connect

I tried to create an item using Square Connect and made it taxable. When I retrieved the item back from Square (even when I retrieved it through a separate call, instead of relying on the return value of the Create call), the taxable field is shown as true, but when I brought up the Register app, that new item was not toggle as taxable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out this confusing point in the API and documentation. The `taxable` field of the `Item` object is in fact **deprecated** (I will update the documentation accordingly). Setting the value of this field has no effect.

Regarding your particular issue, I believe you're saying that you:

1. Created an item with the Connect API
2. Opened Square Register and added your item to a sale
3. Noticed that none of your pre-existing taxes was automatically applied to the item in the sale

After you create an item with the Connect API, you need to specify which taxes are automatically applied to it (by default, no taxes are applied). You do this with the [Apply Fee](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api#put-itemid_feeid) endpoint. The `fees` field of an `Item` object indicates which taxes are automatically applied to an item. If this field is an empty array, no taxes are applied automatically.

Note that regardless of which fees are applied *automatically*, merchants can customize which taxes to apply to an item for a particular sale.